# use time.time() as Timer failed on `**`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a Python 3 learner and recently I was confused by a strange behavior of time.time().

I wrote two pieces of code and timed them with time.time():

### `pow` version

```
from time import time

t0 = time()
x = pow(2, 1000000000)
t1 = time()
print(t1 - t0)
```

> [`pow`image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcgY5.png)

---

### `**` version

```
from time import time

t0 = time()
x = 2 ** 1000000000
t1 = time()
print(t1 - t0)
```

> [`**`image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqJVb.png)

---

`pow`: time_cost = 1.544sec, output = 1.43625617027

`**`: time_cost = 1.526sec, output = 0.0

**Why time.time() doesn't work for `**` version???**

---

More Info:

sys.version=`'3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]'`,

sys.winver=`'3.6-32'`,

sys.platform=`'win32'`,

sys.implementation=`namespace(cache_tag='cpython-36', hexversion=50725616, name='cpython', version=sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0))`

Comment: Could you try it again? Not able to reproduce it. Perhaps there's a typo and you're subtracting the same variables. Plus you've included the wrong code in `**` version.

Comment: If you want to measure the performance of code, please use the `timeit` module instead.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary [image](http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/0060lm7Tly1fj67t8626rj30nx0cptji.jpg) I've tried it again and still time.time() didn't work for `**`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ [timeit image](http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/0060lm7Tly1fj67xa6512j30lt0a4jyp.jpg) It seems that timeit() also failed to time `**`. However, when I tried to time `pow` with timeit(), something strange happened: [image](http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/0060lm7Tly1fj680ybfy1j30sz08dtgw.jpg). timeit() spent 35.79secs running `pow(2, 10000)`! Now i'm more confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the way Python 3 processes certain constant expressions while processing a file.  If you run the program:

```
print("start")
x = 2**1000000000
print("end")
```

you will see that there is a long start-up delay, and then "start" and "end" are printed almost simultaneously.  While the program:

```
print("start")
x = pow(2, 1000000000)
print("end")
```

prints "start", then pauses for a while, and prints "end".

Python "pre-computes" the expression `2**1000000000` while it's initially processing the file (at the byte compilation stage), before the program actually starts running.  In contrast, the expression `pow(2,1000000000)` isn't precomputed; it's byte compiled as a function call and computed when the program actually runs.

Here's another way to see this is happening.  If you create two module files:

```
# starstar.py
x = 2**1000000000

# pow.py
x = pow(2,1000000000)
```

and import them into another program:

```
# main.py
import starstar
import pow
```

and run `python main.py`, then Python will produce byte compiled versions of the modules (maybe in a subdirectory called `__pycache__` or something).  You'll see that the byte-compiled version of the `starstar.pyc` module is huge -- it actually contains a copy of the pre-computed value of `2**1000000000`; but the `pow.pyc` file will be tiny.